# How to calculate depth of each group in column as maximal number of non empty columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function, group-by

I have a dataset:

```
id1     id2    id3    id4
a1      a2     NaN    NaN
a1      a2     a5     NaN
b1      b2     b3     b4
b1      NaN    NaN    NaN
c1      c2     NaN    NaN
```

I want to calculate maximal number of columns with not NaN for each id1. So desired results is:

```
id1   depth
a1     3
b1     4
c1     2
```

How to do that?

Comment: Can you explain more of what you want? Why is depth of a1 in column id1 3? etc.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden depth of a1 in column id1 is 3 because for all rows with id1 = a1 row with maximal number of not NaN columns is 3

Comment: give me 3 minutes, ill send the solution

Answer (score 0):

I created some mock data and stored it in `df`. In order to make the depth count for one column we do the following.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create a sample dataframe
columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
data = {
    'A': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4', 'E5'],
    'B': ['Male', 'Female', 'Female', np.nan, 'Male'],
    'C': [27, 24, 29, np.nan, 25],
    'D': ['Accounting', np.nan, 'Accounting', np.nan, 'Sales']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

ncol = 4
nrow = 5

# for just the first column
print('A', '\t', 'depth')
for i in range(nrow):

    count = 0
    for col in columns:
        if not isinstance(df[col][i], str) and np.isnan(np.asarray([df[col][i]]))[0]:
            break

        count += 1

    print(df['A'][i], '\t', count)
```

1. For each row
2. Start a counter at 0
3. For each element in that row
4. Add 1 to the counter if it is not a nan. If it is a nan, we want to break out of the loop (stop counting).

Output:

```
A        depth
E1       4
E2       3
E3       4
E4       1
E5       4
```

Comment: example that you use here is different. in my example there are not all unique values in column id1. also is it possible to save output as separate data frame. you can check that with my example output will be different than desired one

Comment: Yes you can store the result in a dataframe as well. But i feel like it would be a good skill for you to google how to do so. Just instead of each print, add a new row to the result dataframe.

Comment: Yea so about the unique part. You mean that my code will give you: (a1: 2) and (a1: 3). To solve that you only want (a1: 3), just store them both and keep the longest one...

Answer (score 0):

is this the result you want?

```
df.groupby('id1').apply(lambda x: len(x.dropna(axis=1,how='all').columns))
'''
id1
a1    3
b1    4
c1    2
dtype: int64
```